# NullPointerException when using fragment in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

There are some fragments in my activity.

```
private MainFragment mMainFragment;
... //other fragments
```

Here's my PagerAdapter.

```
private class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.w(TAG, "position: " + position);
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            mMainFragment = MainFragment.newInstance(PAGE_MAIN_INDEX);
            return mMainFragment;
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
    }
}
```

Sometimes, when my app goes to background, the system kills the activity, then if my app return to foreground and system try restore my page. It looks everything is fine, every view shows correctly. 
But when I try to refresh my fragment, my app is crash. Log shows the fragment is null. I don't why. Any ideas?

Here's my Fragment.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = (SubmitTenderActivity) getActivity();
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mResources = getResources();
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getItem()` does not get called again when a Fragment is being restored by the framework, so your `mMainFragment` is null after restoring. `instantiateItem()` method is called for every Fragment that is being restored by the framework so you must reassign mMainFragment again in this method. Change your code as following should solve your problem:

```
private class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.w(TAG, "position: " + position);
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            mMainFragment = MainFragment.newInstance(PAGE_MAIN_INDEX);
            return mMainFragment;
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (position == 0) {
            mMainFragment = (MainFragment)obj;
        } 
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
    }
}
```

Comment: But why the page looks like fine. The view in the fragment are all display normally. It confuses me.

Comment: To restore your app, the framework create new instance of Activitys and Fragments and restoring their states that are saved in "savedInstanceState". It's obvious that your mMainFragment  is null if generate a new Activity instance but do not call the getItem() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position){
        case 0:

            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment2();
        default:
            break;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have to do something in my fragment when user click the menu. So I have keep a strong reference of MainFragment in my activity.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use below method in fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }
```

Comment: I do this  in Fragment.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: dont put in that method. this is overrided method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I think onAttach and onCreate both are overrided method

Comment: I only Override onCreate and onCreateView in the fragment. I post onCreateView above.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you should move the return mMainFragment out of the if statement in method getItem.

Comment: Why,  could you give me some more tips please?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this? Its working fine for me.

```
public class UpdateTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public UpdateTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new AcademicDocumentsFragment();
    case 1:
        return new EmployementDocumentsFragment();
    case 2:
        return new UploadPhotoDetailsFragment();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

Comment: Because I need to do something in my fragment when user click the menu.